# SnowFlake - How to escape a character in lateral flatten input?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently working through Step 2 of this tutorial from Snowflake but am using my own JSON, stored in a column I'll call my_column in a table called my_table:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-query.html

The JSON file I am using has a key that contains the '@' character.

Example:

```html
"@characteristics": {
    "XXX": "XXXX",
    "YYY": "YYYY",
    "ZZZ": "ZZZZ"
    }
```

When I try to use a SELECT statement that includes the FLATTEN function, ie something like this

```html
select
  value:xxx::number
  from
    my_table
  , lateral flatten( input => my_column:@characteristics);
```

When I try this, SnowFlake gives me the error 'SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 57 unexpected '@characteristics'.' I have tried to escape the '@' character in front of attributes but have not had any luck.

Comment: How did you try to escape it?

Comment: I've tried to use \@characteristics and "\@characteristics" but haven't had any success.

Comment: It does not. I get there following error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 57 unexpected '\\'.

Comment: It's most likely the missing `parse json` causing this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes. Try this one:

```
create table my_table ( my_column variant ) as 
select parse_json ( $$ { "@characteristics": {
"XXX": "XXXX",
"YYY": "YYYY",
"ZZZ": "ZZZZ"
}} $$ );

select
value
from my_table
,lateral flatten( input => my_column:"@characteristics");
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Gokhan. When I use double quotes, I am still getting the error. I did not use parse_json in my create table statement as you did, which I'm thinking is why I still get the error. My create table statement followed the SF tutorial [link] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-prerequisites.html

Comment: The SF tutorial you mentioned, also uses parse_json when inserting data. I do not understand how you did not use it. It would be better if you share the exact SQL commands you used for creating and populating data.